# Is it possible to connect view controller to splash screen.xib

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on splash screen where I want to add custom progress bar on splash screen.
So is it possible to Connect view controller to splash screen?
So that I can add some code on view controller to add progress bar on splash screen.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer is you cannot use view controller in your splash view (LaunchScreen.xib).

But you can design LaunchScreen to looks the same as your view controller. Add progress bar, and whatever you want to the view controller and display the view controller as your initial view.

So when the user launch the app the splash screen will change to your view controller, it should be quick and pleasant transition and  you will have a full control on the custom view controller view.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect view controller to splash screen. Instead of that you can take a UIView controller and make it as first screen to launch. Under Build setting you can set any view controller as launch screen.